# JavaScript and CSS working in Dreamweaver but not in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I have an html page and it is getting linked to jquery, javascript and css.  This all works fine in Dreamweaver, but when I put it on a server or run the file locally, it doesn't work.  I have run all 3 files through syntax checkers and there is nothing wrong with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `codepen` and it seems to be working fine:

```
https://codepen.io/vishalkaului/pen/bYedPp
```

Possible problem could be in the path, please crosscheck.

Answer (score 0):

Too much recursion? Wow. So, something in your code is going bonkers re-running itself. Does it give you a clue as to where the recursion is happening? If so, you'll need to trace the code and fix or limit the recursion. It may be the dreamweaver has a larger recursion stack, or some how "fixes" the recursion problem itself. This is why I don't develop in alternate environments than the actual target (in this case, a browser -- or do you have another reason for using dreamweaver?)

Comment: so, I fixed the infinite recursion and it still won't work correctly.  The javascript will log to the console now, but the css is still not to be found.  And as for why I use Dreamweaver, it was in the bundle I bought so I figured I should use it, but I've never had any kind of trouble with it like this before.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like dreamweaver is doing something "for you" that the regular environment isn't doing. Some js include, jQuery include, something like that. Some code post would help. And maybe you should use some console.log statements to see if jQuery is loaded up, or to see if you can establish how far your code is getting before failing. Are there any console messages at all, indicating errors or failures?

Comment: The console doesn't say anything and my code is here https://pastebin.com/d6Z8Zy20.  Ill try to see if the javascript is loading with some log statements like you said EDIT: when I add a console log statement it says too much recursion.